# Trying to Visualize Optimal Decision Tree as Text

Tags: decision-tree

I'm trying to visualize my Decision Tree as Text use the tree.export_text() method but am getting an error telling me I need to specify an argument for the for my parameter grid (param_grid).  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
param_grid={'max_depth': [3], 'max_leaf_nodes': [4], 'min_samples_split': [2]}

decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42, param_grid)

# Retrain the model
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X, y)

# Use the tree.export_text() method to visualize the "optimal" decision tree. 
r = export_text(decision_tree, feature_names=iris['feature_names'])
print(r)

error:

  File "C:\Users\spenc\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15384/3344812307.py", line 8
    decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42, param_grid)
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: Thank you Negash.  I believe I found the solution.  The param_grid was generating an error when I was passing it into the DecisionTreeClassifier b/c it's a dictionary.  When I specified **param_grid, it didn't generate an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to correct the following:

1. First instantiate a new DecisionTreeClassifier object and use as an input parameter "the best params" you get in your gird search before.
2. Replace the (X, y) to (X_train, y_train), in re-training the optimal model.
3. Also add tree to your export_text() as tree.export_text().

I hope this helps or atleast brings you closer to the solution. :)